# Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant returns error

Tags: wso2

For Password grant explained [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS5xx/Resource+Owner+Password+Credentials+Grant): I get the error

> ```
> {
>     "error_description": "The authenticated client is not authorized to use this authorization grant type",
>     "error": "unauthorized_client"
> }
> ```

I am unable to find info on how to authorize this client for this request.

Comment: Are you sure your client id and secret are correct? and the oauth app has the `password` grant type enabled?

Comment: clientid/secret are correct. I am trying to see how to enable password grant type to the app.

Comment: How did you create the oauth app? From UI or API?

Comment: I created the oauth app from the UI

Comment: You should be able to edit it and enabled grant types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to edit the OAuth app and enable grant types like this.

[image]

Then >>>

[image]